# Highcharts Time Series data from C# in a format required by HighCharts

Tags: c#, highcharts

Highcharts requires that the series data be in this format

```
series : {
 data : [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],[x5,y5]]
}
```

My data is coming from ASP.net web application in the form of JSON i.e.

```
[{"time": x1, "value" : y1},{"time": x2, "value" : y2}]
```

In order for the data to work with Highcharts, I have to manually push the objects as an array in an empty array using JavaScript.

```
var tempData = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    tempData.push([item.time,item.value]);
});​
//then add the series using tempData
```

Ideally I would not like this to be done on the browser as it degrades the performance of the application on the client side and I am using large set of data.

On the C# side, this is what I have,

```
public class TimeValuePair
{
  double time {get;set;}
  double value{get;set;}
}
List<TimeValuePair> data= dataFromServer;
```

And I am returning the data as;

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

What is the proper way of dealing with this ?

Comment: You're having an .Asp which runs on the client side, and you want to create the graphs on the server side with data from the client, and then send it back to the client?

Comment: My application is a single page web app. I need to get the data asynchronously.

Comment: I'm assuming you had a look at this: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading ?

Comment: The question is more on C# side. This has nothing to do with lazy loading. I appreciate your help.

Comment: So what you want is to create the list as a string in the format that Highcharts requries (using C#) ?

Comment: Yes. It looks like it should be a string.

Comment: I could create a string by running a for loop and appending each pair, but I was looking for more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to achieve what you want in a compact way:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data.Select(t => new object[] {t.Time, t.Value}))
```

(Not sure what Json serializer you are using, so my example uses the one from System.Web.Extensions)

Answer (score -1):

So you basically want to do this:

> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("series : {data : [");
>
> foreach (var time_value_pair in data)     sb.Append("[" +
>   time_value_pair.time + "," + time_value_pair.value + "]");
>
> sb.Append("]}");

and send `sb.ToString()` who whomever needs the string.